# Remove list element if x% variation

Tags: python

I'm using the `randint()` function to change the values that are initially present on a list. However, I want there to be a range for all of these to change. Specifically, if they go 25% over their initial value or 25% under they are removed from the list, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I tried to do it in a single function but I don't think that's the way so, I made another function which carries the unaltered list. Then I can compare the 2 but I'm not sure how to set the 25% limit for the variation of the values. The way I did it gives me an error when I run the function.

I also tried doing this:

```py
def algoritmo():
     for num in range(len(records)):
         records[num] = records[num][:-1] + (random.uniform(0.75*num, 1.25*num),)
```

However, the values were not in the range I wanted them to be.

```py
records = [
    ('Empresa:', 'Altri', 'Cotação:', 5.37), ('Empresa:', 'BCP', 'Cotação:', 0.13),
    ('Empresa:', 'Corticeira Amorim', 'Cotação:', 10.58), ('Empresa:', 'CTT', 'Cotação:', 5.12),
    ('Empresa:', 'EDP Renováveis', 'Cotação:', 20.64),
    ('Empresa:', 'EDP', 'Cotação:', 4.67), ('Empresa:', 'Galp', 'Cotação:', 8.70),
    ('Empresa:', 'Ibersol', 'Cotação:', 5.82), ('Empresa:', 'Jerónimo Martins', 'Cotação:', 16.83),
    ('Empresa:', 'Mota-Engil', 'Cotação:', 1.35),
    ('Empresa:', 'NOS', 'Cotação:', 3.03), ('Empresa:', 'Novabase', 'Cotação:', 4.60),
    ('Empresa:', 'PHAROL', 'Cotação:', 0.11), ('Empresa:', 'REN', 'Cotação:', 2.37),
    ('Empresa:', 'Semapa', 'Cotação:', 11.50), ('Empresa:', 'Sonae', 'Cotação:', 0.80),
    ('Empresa:', 'Sonac', 'Cotação:', 0.77), ('Empresa:', 'The Navigator Company', 'Cotação:', 2.96)]


def create_random_numbs(input_list):
    output_numbers = []
    for given_number in input_list:
        max = given_number * 1.25
        min = given_number * 0.75
        random_number = random()
        random_number_in_desired_range = min + (random_number * (max - min))
        output_numbers.append(random_number_in_desired_range)
    return output_numbers


def swap():
    input_numbers = [x[-1] for x in records]
    new_numbers_in_desired_range = create_random_numbs(input_numbers)
    new_records = []
    for item, new_number in zip(records, new_numbers_in_desired_range):
        item_as_list = list(item)
        item_as_list[-1] = new_number
        new_records.append(tuple(item_as_list))


create_random_numbs()
swap()

print(records)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, then I think this should work?

```
def create_random_numbs(input_list):
    output_numbers = []
    for given_number in (input_list):
        max = given_number * 1.25
        min = given_number * 0.75
        random_number = random()
        random_number_in_desired_range = min + (random_number * (max - min))
        output_numbers.append(random_number_in_desired_range)

    return output_numbers
```

Note that these are pseudo random numbers so it depends a little bit on your needs. I'm assuming this is fine though because that's what you were doing in the original post.

There's a good article on how this all works [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-python/).

Anyway applied to your problem, this is my two cents - hope it helps:

```
input_numbers = [x[-1] for x in records]
new_numbers_in_desired_range = create_random_numbs(input_numbers)
new_records = []
for item, new_number in zip(records, new_numbers_in_desired_range):
    item_as_list = list(item)
    item_as_list[-1] = new_number
    new_records.append(tuple(item_as_list))
```

EDIT:

Full answer including your code:

```
from random import random

records = [
    ('Empresa:', 'Altri', 'Cotação:', 5.37), ('Empresa:', 'BCP', 'Cotação:', 0.13),
    ('Empresa:', 'Corticeira Amorim', 'Cotação:', 10.58), ('Empresa:', 'CTT', 'Cotação:', 5.12),
    ('Empresa:', 'EDP Renováveis', 'Cotação:', 20.64),
    ('Empresa:', 'EDP', 'Cotação:', 4.67), ('Empresa:', 'Galp', 'Cotação:', 8.70),
    ('Empresa:', 'Ibersol', 'Cotação:', 5.82), ('Empresa:', 'Jerónimo Martins', 'Cotação:', 16.83),
    ('Empresa:', 'Mota-Engil', 'Cotação:', 1.35),
    ('Empresa:', 'NOS', 'Cotação:', 3.03), ('Empresa:', 'Novabase', 'Cotação:', 4.60),
    ('Empresa:', 'PHAROL', 'Cotação:', 0.11), ('Empresa:', 'REN', 'Cotação:', 2.37),
    ('Empresa:', 'Semapa', 'Cotação:', 11.50), ('Empresa:', 'Sonae', 'Cotação:', 0.80),
    ('Empresa:', 'Sonac', 'Cotação:', 0.77), ('Empresa:', 'The Navigator Company', 'Cotação:', 2.96)]


def create_random_numbs(input_list):
    output_numbers = []
    for given_number in input_list:
        max = given_number * 1.25
        min = given_number * 0.75
        random_number = random()
        random_number_in_desired_range = min + (random_number * (max - min))
        output_numbers.append(random_number_in_desired_range)
    return output_numbers


def swap():
    input_numbers = [x[-1] for x in records]
    new_numbers_in_desired_range = create_random_numbs(input_numbers)
    new_records = []
    for item, new_number in zip(records, new_numbers_in_desired_range):
        item_as_list = list(item)
        item_as_list[-1] = new_number
        new_records.append(tuple(item_as_list))
    return new_records

print(swap())
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was going for, I am still however getting an error that says input_list isn't defined when I run the function like this: `create_random_numbs(input_list)` and if I don't put it in I get missing parameter. I edited my original code to see what I've put in

Comment: Hey @Nuno, glad that's what you were going for. 

tl;dr, delete create_random_numbs(), add return new_records to end of your swap() function definition. Then call print(swap()) instead of swap().

You don't need to call create_random_numbs() at the end of the code since it's called in your swap() function. You need to make the swap function return the new_records list object.

Comment: didn't realize it was already called. However, now it gives out a couple more errors, here when the function is called ` new_numbers_in_desired_range = create_random_numbs(input_numbers)`  and here `random_number = random()` and I get a TypeError saying 'module' object is not callable which I think has something to do with the random function

Comment: Have you got from random import random at the top of your script?

Comment: yup I imported random

Comment: Hm I just included an edit in my answer of your code that is working for me

Comment: it is working, I thought I had exactly that but apparently not, sorry! and thanks for the help!

Comment: sorry for being annoying but where exactly does the new list get stored? it's supposed to be inside the new_records list but I can only call it by calling the function, and in another part of the code I wanna call that list but I can't get a `random.sample()` from a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234934/discussion-between-osint-alex-and-nuno).